# Saving data in div between changing states and controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So the problem is this, in my website i have a `div` that handles GET and POST requests. So far so Good.

When i POST something on view A and then it is PROCESSING, I change the view/state, controller to View B it looses the data, it doesn't get data back from the API. Normally when data is received i get pop up windows saying SUCCESS, but on change nothing happens. Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: @AlexisWilke Nope.. sorry.. company code..

Answer (score 0):

That's because HTTP is a stateless system.  I'm not sure of the specifics since your question is vague, but if you want this "DIV" to appear on ViewB, you'll have to store the div's data somehow.

Three ways off of the top of my head:

Cookies (Which I'd not use), or...

Serialize the DIV: When submitting the POST data from ViewA to the controller to create ViewB, serialize the DIV and include with the POST.  When you render ViewB, include the data from the POST and recreate a copy of the DIV with those same values.

AJAX your site: Design your site so that content is pulled to/from the server via AJAX, while the 'initial view (e.g., ViewA)' persists and never gets unloaded. You can replace entire blocks or other objects with new values from the site, while keeping everything else intact.